# Dr. Watson Crash Handler Stealing Focus from Direct3D9 Fullscreen game. Can anything be done?

Tags: directx-9, lost-focus

I have been tasked with developing a game for an embedded device developed by a 3rd party.
The device runs Windows XP - win monitors. The game MUST use DirectX9 (D3D9Ex is forbidden).

The 3rd party replaces the directX9 DLL's with their own in-house developed D9D libraries. The reason being that they sometimes need to display notifications into our scene. I believe the Games Library 'Steam' does something similar. Behind the scenes, i suspect that they forward calls into the real D3D libraries, and Hijack the Present() call for extra rendering.

My problem is - One of the unrelated background applications developed by the 3rd party keeps crashing. This pops up the familiar 'Whatever.exe has encounter a problem and needs to close, sorry for the inconvenience.'

When this happens, my fullscreen application loses focus, and the d3ddevice enters the *lost device* state.

The game then does the usual lost device recovery dance. This works perfectly when linking directly against the Microsoft D3D libraries. HOWEVER, when linked against the modified 3rd party libraries - And the device becomes lost whilst the modified DLL's are rendering notifications to our window, the d3ddevice->Reset() fails. Not all D3DPOOL_DEFAULT textures have been released. The 3rd party has confirmed that the modified DLL's will fail on a lost device. Furthermore, they don't consider this a bug in their modified DLL's.

The 3rd party consider this a bug in my code. They say that the bug is that my game lost focus in the first place.

I have claimed that the bug is not on my side. The bug is:

- *modified DLL make a lost device recovery impossible.*
- *3rd party background application crashes, causing Dr.Watson to gain focus.*

The 3rd party claim that other developers don't share my problem, And other developers are creating games in fullscreen exclusive mode. TLDR: What more can be done !?

Windows are created with CreateWindowEx with dwExStyle WS_EX_TOPMOST.
A single D3DDevice is created for both windows with the D3DCREATE_ADAPTERGROUP_DEVICE flag (Different SwapChain per Window).

Is it really *my fault* for losing focus!?
Is there anything more I can do?

Thanks in advance for any advice.